# scikit-learn kmeans clustering overflow error

Tags: scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

While finding **KMeans** elbow, it showing overflow error

```
elbow=[]

for i in range(30):

    model = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    model.fit(feature_matrix)
    elbow.append(abs(model.score(feature_matrix)))
```

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py:90: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  n_local_trials = 2 + int(np.log(n_clusters))
```

and it gives `overflow` error

Answer (score 3):

It might be because you start with a number of cluster `i=0`. 
With the function `range`, you start from 0.

`Kmeans(nclusters=0)` will fail, because it will try to calculate `log(0)`

You can just change it by `Kmeans(n_cluster=i+1)`, if you want the number of clusters to be tested to varied from 1 to 30 (included).

Comment: Thank you. I've been stuck with the same.